# Verbose output for R package building

Tags: r, cran

I am trying to compile a package using:

```
devtools::build()
```

At some point C/C++ compilation errors crop up; however, I'm having difficulty debugging them because I don't know what command was used to compile them. Is there a way to get the build commands to generate verbose output similar to `make` or `ninja -v` where each file's compilation command is listed?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `R CMD INSTALL` at the command line, you'll see all the commands and compile errors.

I wouldn't expect `devtools::build` to be compiling source, unless you've specified `binary = TRUE`.  You'd use `devtools::install` for that, and it includes the argument `quiet`, which defaults to `TRUE`:  so set it to `FALSE` and you should see the compile steps.